# What is a .bundle file and how do I run it?

Tags: bundle

What is a .bundle file and how do I run it?

Answer (score 19):

`.bundle` is also used by Git. If you have a Git bundle, use Git to checkout from the bundle. It is basically just a remote repository residing on your filesystem.

Comment: FWIW: Here's the Git documentation on bundle with examples
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle#_example

And the all important:

git clone -b master /home/me/tmp/file.bundle

Comment: `git clone file.bundle file` to "unzip" it

Answer (score 16):

VMWare Workstation for Linux is delivered as a .bundle file. It begins with a shell script, and can be run with

```
sudo sh ./myFile.bundle
```

You can use `more` to see the shell script at the beginning of the file.

Comment: I was lead to this question because I was trying to install VMWare on Linux. Is there any advantage to this format over a more standard Linux type of installation method?

Comment: Also, I was also looking for how to run the VMware installer file which is a .bundle . 
So thanks for the nice answer. :D

Answer (score 6):

The `.bundle` file extension references:

1. At [**FILEext**](http://filext.com/file-extension/BUNDLE#) -- Bundle (Plug-ins and Add-ons)

   > The BUNDLE file type is primarily associated with 'OS X' by Apple Inc.. Used for various plug-in and add-on features for OS X. BUNDLE files sometimes contain .PLUGIN files in Mac OS X.
   >
   > Other applications associated with file type BUNDLE:
   >   [iMovie 3](http://www.apple.com/imovie/) (Plug-in Bundle) by Apple Inc.

   - At [**FileInfo**](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/bundle) -- Mac OS X Application Plug-in
   - You could also get a [Linux installable for VMWare](http://www.vmware.com/download/player/download.html) as a `.bundle` file.
     [Ubuntu forum reference](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware/Workstation) to work with that.

Answer (score 1):

File Type: Mac OS X Application Plug-in

**Bundle** file or plug-in that adds extra features to the operating system or an application in Mac OS X; examples include support for audio and video cards, custom printer filters, extensions for Dreamweaver, and additional effects in iMovie.

Most bundle files can be found within the /System/Library directory; others are stored in application or applications support folders.

*NOTE: Bundle files are referenced by the programs below and should not be opened manually.*

Program(s) that open bundle files:

> Mac OS    Mac OS  Apple Mac OS X
>   (operating system)
>
> Adobe CS3 programs
>
> Microsoft Office programs
>
> Perl engine

*[Source](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/bundle)*

Answer (score 0):

A `.bundle` file is an execute file for linux to install a program. A way to install this file extensions is:

```
sudo bash filename
```

For example:

```
sudo bash myinstaller.bundle
```

Answer (score 0):

*In additional to the other, more common, more helpful answers here;*

Try to open the `*.bundle` file with a plain-text editor as some applications export several files at once and insert the content of all files into a single bundle file.